# POST method for Twitter in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, post, twitter

I have a problem with the POST method and authorization of twitter for iOS developing.
I can't understand how is implemented the request in Objective-C.
I want to change the profile image with this POST url

> https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/update_profile_image.json

[from Twitter documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/account/update_profile_image#oauth-tool)

I tried with the TWiOSReverseAuthExample code from [here](https://github.com/seancook/TWReverseAuthExample), but doesn't work, help me! 
Thank you everyone for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a research for some topics to do so:

1) twitter app authentication for ios and getting access token

2) NSMutableURLRequest

3) XML Parser OR json Parser for ios

then ask in detail in one of those topics